# Facebook Comments - Force user to login to site?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-comments

I was wondering if I can require a user to login to my site before they can comment using facebook comments? Right now if a user views a page with facebook comments (because I have a public facing section) then they can comment even if they aren't logged into my site (because they are logged into facebook).

Can I have a "View Only" mode for comments or something similar? If not then I have to take the comments off the public facing site which I really don't want to do.

Thanks for any help!

JAck

Comment: Facebook comments were designed to make the communication easier, because everyone has FB account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always hide the comments box until the user logs in.  Just subscribe to the `FB.Event.subscribe()`'s `auth.statusChange` to monitor for when the user's status changes.  Also you will need to check their current login status during page load (see `FB.getLoginStatus()`).  Then when you know they're logged in, show the comments box.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is not possible...

but giving you some reference that you get the callback after facebook user posts comments .

reference url : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
alert('The commentID of the comment is: ' + response.commentID);
});
```

Waiting for some other comments for this thread.